# Admin: Get all user for Custom Role

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I made a custom post type evenement with these capabilities. Here, I just put the capabilities parameters.

```
'capability_type' => 'evenement',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'capabilities' => array(
    // meta caps (don't assign these to roles)
    'edit_post' => 'edit_evenement',
    'read_post' => 'read_evenement',
    'delete_post' => 'delete_evenement',

    // primitive/meta caps
    'create_posts' => 'create_evenements',

    // primitive caps used outside of map_meta_cap()
    'edit_posts'  => 'edit_evenements',
    'edit_others_posts'  => 'manage_evenements',
    'publish_posts' => 'publish_evenements',
    'read_private_posts' => 'read',

    // primitive caps used inside of map_meta_cap()
    'read' => 'read',
    'delete_posts' => 'delete_evenements',
    'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_private_evenements',
    'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_evenements',
    'delete_others_posts' => 'manage_evenements',
    'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_evenements',
    'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_evenements'
    )
```

And for the add_cap function I use

```
// CPT event
function manage_event_capabilities() {
    $admin = get_role('administrator');
    $institution = get_role('institution');
    $institutionspecial = new WP_User(105);
    $caps = array(
        'create_evenements',
        'delete_evenements',
        'delete_private_evenements',
        'delete_published_evenements',
        'edit_evenements',
        'manage_evenements',
        'publish_evenements'
    );

    foreach($caps as $cap) {
        $admin->add_cap($cap);
    }

    // $admin->remove_cap('exec_php');

    // basique
    $institution->add_cap('upload_files');

    // event
    $institution->add_cap('create_evenements');
    $institution->add_cap('edit_evenements');
    $institution->remove_cap('publish_evenements');
    $institution->add_cap('delete_evenements');
    $institution->add_cap('special_institution');


}
```

Everything works perfect, except for one think. The admin, can not list all the user who have this custom role `institution`. If I want to change the author, I just have the current one (with institution role) or all the **normal** author of the website.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I find the solution and put the link related. That would be easier to undertand for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, that's a WordPress 4 year's bug. Here is the Summary from [DrewAPicture](https://profiles.wordpress.org/DrewAPicture)

> changed from manually created user roles not showing in author dropdown irregardless of assigned capabilities to Manually created user roles not showing in author dropdown regardless of assigned capabilities

Please see [ticket 16841](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16841) for more details.

The only simple solution I find is to change the author with a custom role to the normal Author role. Then attribute the custom post to this author and change back the same author with the custom role.